# Incorporating a string to a file reader

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was just messing around with the file creating in python and got a program to print the words in the code each on a seperate line. What I was wondering and trying is doing this by using a string. I was trying to use a string called

```
input_str = "python is cool"
```

I wanted the program to print that statement with each word on a new line, but I had no idea where to start. Would I use a for loop and the split method?

```
f = open("file1.txt","w")
f.write("python\nis\ncool")
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

are you wondering something like below?

```
input_str = "python is cool"
input_str_list = input_str.split() 
for word in input_str_list:
    print(word)
```

in which the `split` method will split the string by space as default, and return a list as result

Answer (score 0):

```
[print(i) for i in "python is cool".split(" ")]
```

you can use the split method to separate each word in the string into a list, then use a for loop to iterate through and print each item in the list.